# PHPExcel permission error on Windows fileshare

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, phpexcel, windows-server-2012

I have PHPExcel running on a Ubuntu server and I am having permission issues.

```
[Tue Jul 25 13:39:58.672575 2017] [:error] [pid 1456] [client 192.168.0.18:57924] PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: Permission denied in /var/www/html/i/phpExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php on line 388, referer: http://192.168.0.32/i/previewPO.php
[Tue Jul 25 13:39:58.677278 2017] [:error] [pid 1456] [client 192.168.0.18:57924] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PHPExcel_Writer_Exception: Could not close zip file /home/User/Main/Inventory/POs/t/PO_6295.xlsx. in /var/www/html/i/phpExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php:389\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/i/savePOToExcel.php(143): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007->save('/home/User/Mai...')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/i/phpExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php on line 389, referer: http://192.168.0.32/i/previewPO.php
```

I am trying to save to a Windows fileshare I have mounted on the Ubuntu Server.

If I ssh into the server and access the fileshare though that I can create/modify/delete files with out a problem and if I tell PHPExcel to save files locally (linux server) it works fine - i'm not sure where the problem is.

Here are the instructions I followed to mount the fileshare:
 https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Does anyone have any ideas how I can make this work?

Comment: What exact command line did you use for mounting the partition? Is your SSH user the same as the webserver user? If not, does the webserver have write permissions on the `/home/User/Mai…` (the one from the error message) folder?

Comment: @lxg I edited my `etc/fstab` file `//servername/sharename  /media/windowsshare  cifs  username=msusername,password=mspassword,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0`. The username I use to SSH into the server is different than the username I connect to the fileserver with. The username I've authenticated to the fileserver with is that of the administrator - I should be allowed to do anything.

Comment: On the wiki page you’ve mentioned, it says something about setting access modes to `0777`. Can you try that? (Don’t forget to remount/reboot if doing this via `/etc/fstab`.)